# Stop onclick event, once onblur event got active

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, events, dom-events

I have one text field and one button, I just want to ignore `onclick` event on button, when `onblur` events got activated. I tried a few methods but didn't work for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction(event)"> 
<button onclick="calldiv(event)">Click</button>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
 // event.preventDefault();
 //   event.stopPropagation();
 // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
console.log("blur");
}
function calldiv(event) {
 console.log("div");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result...

1st time button got clicked:-blur

2nd time button got clicked:-div

Comment: unclear what you are trying to do exactly. So when they have the input in focus and then they click on the button, you do not want the click of the button to register? Seems like an odd use case.

Comment: yes, and next time I want button click.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to solve it is to make an if statement inside `calldiv` function

```html
<body>
  Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onblur="myFunction(event)" />
  <button id="button" onclick="calldiv(event)">Click</button>
  <script>
    let blured = false;
    function calldiv(event) {
      console.log(blured);
      if (!blured) {
        console.log("div");
      } else {
        blured = false;
      }
    }
    const currentButton = document.getElementById("button");

    function myFunction(event) {
      console.log("blur");
      blured = true;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Once onblur got deactivated, then div should get displayed in console.